# sending body contents through email using phpmailer

Tags: php

I am trying to add fileds in phpmailer() in jobbersbase.

but i am not getting how to add it properly

i am using like this, but it is mailing only $mailer->Body = ($data['apply_location1']);, i mean the one just above the $mailer->AltBody = $msg; statement. but i want to send all the info through mail.

```
public function MailApplyOnline($data)
{
    $mailer = $this->getConfiguredMailer();
    $subject = $this->emailTranslator->GetApplyOnlineSubject($data);

    $msg = $data['apply_msg'];

    $msg .= $this->emailTranslator->GetApplyOnlineMsg($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    $mailer->SetFrom($data['apply_email'], $data['apply_name']);
    $mailer->AddAddress($data['company_email'], $data['company_name']);
    $mailer->Subject = $subject;
    $mailer->Body = $this->nl2br($msg);
    $mailer->Body = ($data['apply_company']);
    $mailer->Body = ($data['apply_contact']);
    $mailer->Body = ($data['apply_title']);
    $mailer->Body = ($data['apply_location']);
    $mailer->Body = ($data['apply_location1']);
    $mailer->AltBody = $msg;

    if ($data['attachment_filename'] != '')
    {
        $mailer->AddAttachment($data['attachment_path'], $data['attachment_filename']);
    }

    if ($mailer->Send())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bottom $mailer->Body keep replacing the one on top. So you end up getting only $data['apply_location1']. Why not you merge them in a temporary variable first then only set $mailer->Body = $temp_variable;.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a local variable $body and keep appending whatever you need to add for the body content.

```
$body = "";
$body .= $this->nl2br($msg) . "<br/>";
$body .= ($data['apply_company']) . "<br/>";
$body .= ($data['apply_contact']) . "<br/>";
$body .= ($data['apply_title']) . "<br/>";
$body .= ($data['apply_location']) . "<br/>";
$body .= ($data['apply_location1']) . "<br/>";

$mailer->Body = $body;
```

The reason your code fails is because you keep overwriting $mailer->Body.